# Resize\zoom an HTML content within a td

Tags: html, innerhtml

Here is an example:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td width="400px" id='myTD'></td>
   </td>
</table>
```

here is the external code:

```
protected string GetHtml()
{
     return "<table><tr><td width="800px"></td></tr></table>";
}
```

Since the width of 'myTD' is smaller than the width of the external code the displayed code is getting out of the main table boundaries , I dont want the innerHTML of 'myTD' to make the main table wider.
Suffice to say that as the external HTML code is given from outside I can't change it without ruin it as I'll never know which width or heights will be essential for the code and which wouldn't.

Comment: With out seeing any code of yours, I can only say, you need to set either the `width`, `height`, or `max-width`, `max-height` CSS properties of your elements.

Comment: The mechanism of what is happening is a bit unclear. Please explain more. And get rid of the `px`, or change the widths into inline styles.

Comment: I am trying to load the returned Value from GetHTML() to 'myID' innerHTML, but it widths the entire table as the innerHTML width is bigger than 'myTD' width.

Comment: OK, so what should happen? Should the rest of the content be hidden, or do you want a horizontal scrollbar to appear in your td?

Comment: Yes it is an option indeed, but all I know is i DONT want it to pass the boundaries of the main table as it does at my project, and this happens due to the fact that 'myID' width is 'X' (400px) and the width of the TD from the external code is >'X' (800px)

Comment: You mean you don't want your td to grow to 800px? Or do you mean the content is partially displayed outside of your td and you don't want that?

Comment: I dont want my content to partially display outside of the TD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't easy in a way that's compatible with all browsers, but I did come up with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
   #myID {width:400px; overflow:scroll}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><div id='myID'>

     <table><tr><td width="800"><hr style="width:792px"</td></tr></table>

    </div></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

(or as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hSJD/)). That is, by adding a new element inside your `td` that gets the scrollbars. Trying to apply `overflow:scroll` to a table cell doesn't work the same on all browsers.
Hope you can use this.